# If $A\subset A'$ are Boolean algebras, can the Stone space of $A$ be embedded in the Stone space of $A'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

I think the following is true but I can't find a reference. If $A$ and $A'$ are Boolean algebras, and $A \subset A'$, then $S_A$ can be embedded in $S_{A'}$, where $S_A$ and $S_{A'}$ are the associated Stone spaces.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Greg

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $A\subset A'$ iff $S_A$ is a quotient space, not a subspace, of $S_{A'}. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

This is false.  For instance, let $A'=P(\mathbb{N})$ and let $A$ be the subalgebra consisting of finite or cofinite sets.  Then $S_A\cong\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ and $S_{A'}\cong\beta\mathbb{N}$, but $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ does not embed in $\beta\mathbb{N}$.  (As a sketch of how to prove this, suppose $i:\mathbb{N}\to\beta\mathbb{N}$ is an embedding.  Then we can find disjoint subsets $A_n\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $A_n$ is in the ultrafilter $i(n)$ for each $n$.  This means the set $A=\bigcup_n A_{2n}$ is in $i(n)$ iff $n$ is even, and so the sequence $(i(n))$ cannot converge in $\beta\mathbb{N}$ and $i$ cannot be extended to $\infty$.)